# When I try to log into MySQL via command line, keeps saying "unknown database 'magento2'"

Tags: mysql

When I try to log into MySQL via command line, keeps saying "unknown database 'magento2'"

Any ideas why? Tried as my username and root, getting the same message. If I can't log into mysql, how could I create a database to begin with of that name? So confused.

Answer (score 0):

You should separate between your database application and a logical database. MySQL server is your database application / server.

When you're logging on to MySQL, you're choosing which *logical* database you would like to work with. A logical database is actually a container of objects such as tables, triggers, views, etc.

So when you see the error `unknown database X`, it's because you installed the MySQL server, but didn't create the logical database.

To see a list of all logical databases in your server, login to MySQL and run the command `show databases;`

To create your database, run the command `create database magento2;`

Now when you login to that database, it should be there and you can start creating your tables and query data from them.

Comment: Right, but I can't create a database. Because it won't log me into mysql to create the database in the first place....doesn't make any sense...every time I try to login, I receive that error message instead.

Comment: Which command are you using? Do you write the database name (magneto2) anywhere in the command? If so, remove that part. That will allow you to login to MySQL without trying to access a specific database, which later will allow you to create it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found that the database name was set in a cnf file. Perhaps you have something similar.